# How to handle savedState in Android for navGraphViewModels

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, viewmodel

I'm using `navGraphViewModels` for my 3 fragments(A, B & C) its working like a wizard.
I want to keep data from Fragment A and B and retrieve that in Fragment C.

I am setting values in `viewmodel` from Fragment A and Fragment B.
Once reached Fragment C, I am retrieving it.

Its working fine if the settings for *Developer options -> don't keep activities is OFF*.
But if its ON, I am losing the data saved from A & B.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Right now the issue is handled using onSaveInstanceState in all the 3 fragments. 

i.e. saving the values in onSaveInstanceState and reloading it in onViewCreated

Any other better solutions?